# Не запускается время при симуляции modelsim

Tags: verilog, rtl, system-verilog

Разрабатываю простой модуль на systemverilog. В тестбенче для сигнала тактирования прописываю:

always #25 clk_i = ~clk_i;

В предыдущих программах все работало отлично, никаких ошибок и нареканий не было. Симуляция старых проектов работает, а этого нет. Работаю в quartus, симуляция в modelsim.
[image: modelsim]

Answer (score 0):

Сигнал clk_i в неопределенном состоянии. Ему нужно задать начальное значение в блоке `initial`